# Is there a simple way to use an integral generic type in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust

I have a series of functions that are almost identical, differing only in type and a constant. For example:

```
fn update16(table: &[u16], init: u16, xs: &[u8]) -> u16 {
    xs.iter().fold(init, |acc, x| { (acc << 8) ^ table[(((acc >> 8) as u8) ^ x) as usize] })
}

fn update32(table: &[u32], init: u32, xs: &[u8]) -> u32 {
    xs.iter().fold(init, |acc, x| { (acc << 8) ^ table[(((acc >> 24) as u8) ^ x) as usize] })
}
```

So I thought about making this function generic on the type:

```
trait Update<T> {
    fn update(table: &[T], init: T, xs: &[u8]) -> T;
}
```

I eventually was able to implement this:

```
use std::ops::Shl;
use std::ops::Shr;
use std::ops::BitXor;
use std::mem::size_of;

extern crate num;
use num::ToPrimitive;

struct Normal;

impl<
    T: Copy + Shl<u8, Output = T> + Shr<usize, Output = T> + BitXor<Output = T> + ToPrimitive,
> CrcUpdate<T> for Normal {
    fn update(table: &[T], init: T, xs: &[u8]) -> T {
        xs.iter().fold(init, |acc, x| {
            (acc << 8) ^
                table[(ToPrimitive::to_u8(&(acc >> ((8 * size_of::<T>()) - 8))).unwrap() ^ x) as
                          usize]
        })
    }
}
```

It was significantly more complicated than I expected. I had to use a bunch of traits, define an empty struct, include an external crate and obscure the basic calculation somewhat. It certainly took many more lines than the original.

Is this the right way in Rust to use generics for integers? Or am I missing a much simpler way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

**Handling integral types uniformly is not smooth.**

The standard library does not provide any "unifying" trait for handling numbers in a uniform fashion, as you just discovered here. It's unclear what the best design would be, and therefore crates like `num` have attempted to explore the design space.

So, yes, if you wish to handle multiple integrals in generic ways, you will have to either pull in external crates (such as `num`) or suffer some pain.

**However, you can use simpler code.**

First of all, defining a `struct` and `trait` as such is completely unnecessary. Rust has generic functions:

```
fn update<T>(table: &[T], init: T, xs: &[u8]) -> T
where
    T: Copy + Shl<u8, Output = T> + Shr<usize, Output = T> + BitXor<Output = T> + ToPrimitive,
{
    xs.iter().fold(init, |acc, x| {
        (acc << 8)
            ^ table[(ToPrimitive::to_u8(&(n >> ((8 * size_of::<T>()) - 8))).unwrap() ^ x) as usize]
    })
}
```

Secondly, in the name of readability, I would encourage you NOT to use `ToPrimitive::to_u8` directly, as it really obscures the code here.

If it's a one-off, then you may either define a variable or wrap its use into a function.

```
fn upper8<T>(n: T) -> u8 {
    ToPrimitive::to_u8(&(n>> ((8 * size_of::<T>()) - 8))).unwrap()
}
```

Otherwise, you can define your own "byte selection" trait. It takes a couple more lines right now, but makes it up with a clearer interface adapted to your domain.

```
trait SelectByte: Sized {
    fn bytes(&self) -> usize { mem::size_of::<Self>() }
    fn lower(&self, n: usize) -> u8;
    fn upper(&self, n: usize) -> u8 { self.lower(self.bytes() - n - 1) }
}

impl SelectByte for u16 {
    fn lower(&self, n: usize) -> u8 {
        assert!(n <= 1);
        ((*self >> (n * 8)) & 255u16) as u8
    }
}

impl SelectByte for u32 {
    fn lower(&self, n: usize) -> u8 {
        assert!(n <= 3);
        ((*self >> (n * 8)) & 255u32) as u8
    }
}
```

*Note: you would implement it for `u8`, `u64` and `u128` if necessary.*

And this gives a simpler-looking result:

```
fn update<T>(table: &[T], init: T, xs: &[u8]) -> T
where
    T: Copy + Shl<u8, Output = T> + BitXor<Output = T> + SelectByte,
{
    xs.iter().fold(init, |acc, x| {
        (acc << 8) ^ table[(acc.upper(0) ^ x) as usize]
    })
}
```

Finally, if you find yourself enumerating the same set of constraints over and over, feel free to define a new trait for it:

```
trait Numeric: Copy + Shl<u8, Output = Self> + BitXor<Output = Self> + SelectByte {}

impl<T> Numeric for T
    where T: Copy + Shl<u8, Output = T> + BitXor<Output = T> + SelectByte
{}
```

And then use your shortcut:

```
fn update<T: Numeric>(table: &[T], init: T, xs: &[u8]) -> T {
    xs.iter().fold(init, |acc, x| { (acc << 8) ^ table[(acc.upper(0) ^ x) as usize] })
}
```

*Which by the way, is the whole idea of the `num` crate if I remember correctly.*

The one pain point you cannot abstract away is that Rust will not allow a literal to be "painlessly" convertible into an abstract `T`. You can use `num::FromPrimitive` for that, but... yes, it doesn't exactly feel great.

Comment: Is there a way to use the num crate to avoid all/most of this extra stuff? In my original implementation, I had to use it anyway.

Comment: @Roxy: I am not too familiar with the crate, so... maybe?

Comment: Pretty sure you are looking for [`Integer`](https://docs.rs/num/0.1.42/num/trait.Integer.html).